# T-SQL how to filter by multiple criteria but prioritize what is returned?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the data below.

```
create table #results (
    id int
    , result_attr char(1)
    , result varchar(100)
)

insert into 
    #results (id, result_attr, result)
values 
    (1, 'E', '***ERROR')
    , (2, 'E', '***CORRECTED')
    , (3, 'E', '***RESULTED')
    , (4, 'E', '***AMENDED')
    , (4, 'E', 'FOO')
    , (5, 'E', 'ERROR***')
    , (5, 'E', 'CORPOREAL')
    , (6, 'E', '***CORRECTED')
    , (7, 'E', '***RESULTED')
    , (7, 'E', 'ABUNDANT')
    , (7, 'E', 'PLENTITUDE')
    , (8, 'E', 'INCORRECT')
    , (9, 'A', 'HIGH')
    , (10, 'A', 'LOW')

select *
from #results

drop table #results
```

The complete result set is:

[image: complete result set]

My desired result set is:

[image: desired result set]

This doesn't quite work:

```
select
    res.id
    , res.result_attr
    , res.result
from #results as res
where
    (charindex('***', res.result) > 0 or res.result_attr = 'E')
```

Tricky part being that I would want to exclude ID #4 with result "FOO" as well as ID #5 with result "CORPOREAL" and ID #7 with results "ABUNDANT" and "PLENTITUDE", but I want to keep ID #8 with result "INCORRECT". All in all, I want to exclude the following:

[image: excluded result set]

I've tried some windowing functions and other things, but am a bit stuck on this one. I would appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` analytical function with conditional ordering as follows:

```
Select * from
(select
    res.id
    , res.result_attr
    , res.result
    , row_number() over (partition by res.id 
                         order by case when charindex('***', res.result) > 0 
                                  then 1 else 2 end) as rn
from #results as res
where
    (charindex('***', res.result) > 0 or res.result_attr = 'E') t
Where rn = 1
Order by id
```

Comment: Thanks Popeye. This worked perfectly. Didn't realize you could do conditional ordering!

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
select
    res.id
    , res.result_attr
    , res.result
from results as res
where res.result LIKE '%***%' OR res.result = 'INCORRECT';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0688217b50f8bc1cc4f8e7aecd384297)**